# Skyrim Max general quest stats?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I would like to assess how far I am away from "completion" of the game as far as that is possible.

I know that there are radiant quests that repeat endlessly, but I would like to know which of the quests stats in the "general stats" tab have a max value and what it is. I could not find a list so far on either of the two game wikis or elsewhere.

Comment: @desaivv I want to know both :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of the stats in the General Stats screen have no fixed limit due to them counting "renewable resources"—there will always be more ingredients to collect and wolves to kill.

Those that do have limits (not counting DLC or mods, which make them potentially infinite as time goes on) have these:

### General

- Books Read: [470](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Books)
- Houses Owned: [5](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses)
- Stores Invested In: [35](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Stores)
- Locations Discovered: [362](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Discoverable)
- Standing Stones Found:[13](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Standing_Stone)
- Skill Books Read: [90](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skill_Books) *(5 for each 18 skills)*

### Quests

- Main Quests Completed: [19](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Main_Quest) *(17, if you don't choose the two optional quests)*
- Side Quests Complete: [33](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Quests-Side_Quests)
- Civil War Quests Completed: [16](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Quests-Imperial_Legion) *(Imperial side; [15](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Quests-Stormcloaks) if you side with the Stormloacks)*
- Dark Brotherhood Quests Completed: [32](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Quests-Dark_Brotherhood)
- Daedric Quests Completed: [17](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Quests-Daedric) *(note that the one Radiant-using quest is not a normal repeatable quest)*

### Magic

- Spells Learned: [108](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spells)
- Words of Power Learned: 60 *(three per Shout)*
- Words of Power Unlocked: 60
- Shouts Learned: [20](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Shouts#Available_Dragon_Shouts)
- Shouts Unlocked: 20
- Shouts Mastered: 20

<sub>*Sources as linked.*</sub>

Comment: Cool! you would not have the DLC also by chance?